# List elements with a specific directive

Tags: angularjs

This might be a bit abstract since I dont have any code. 
Can i get a list of elements with a specific directive and then use that list to communicate with those elements via the directive?

Thanks!

Edit: It looks like I should inject a service in to my directive and let the directive "register" with my service and then handle the changes/communication there.

Comment: Please add some code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually upvoted your question because I like it. While you can use some css selection magic, an angular way would be for your directives to register themselves with a service at some common place, and then you'd be able to use get a handle on them using that service.

Edit:
Take a look at this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2Zoq5sTigmRtBgUIOWv2?p=preview

It is a very naive approach at which we define a thingy called RegistryService, and each of our direcives registers to the service during its link phase:

```
.service('RegistryService', function(){
  var REGISTERED_DIRECTIVES = [];

  return {
    register: function(directive){
      REGISTERED_DIRECTIVES.push(directive);
    },
    unregister: function(directive){
      _.remove(REGISTERED_DIRECTIVES, function(dir){
        return dir === directive;
      });
    },
    get : function(){
      return REGISTERED_DIRECTIVES;
    }
  };
})
```

And the linkage/register:

```
.directive('myDirective', ['RegistryService', function(RegistryService){
  return {
    template : '<div>directive-here</div>',
    link: function(scope, attr, element){
      RegistryService.register(element);
    }
  }
}])
```

Then, you should be able to whatever you want with the element of the directive. However, a more Angular approach would be to putting stuff in the scope of the directive and it would react to scope changes rather than brutally manipulating the css/whatever you are doing by getting the element.

Comment: So I would inject the service in my directive and then let the directive listen to changes in that service?
Or am I far off?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. And also, you would be able to communicate with your directives through the service.

Comment: Thanks! I might add some code to this entry to make it more clear and also provide a better answer. I marked your answer as THE answer.